# Dynamic server error when i used headers | Next.js App Router

Tags: reactjs, next.js

What should I fix to avoid getting this error? Can't I both use 'generateStaticParams()' and check which device the visitor entered from? If i use `export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'` this time i will sacrifice page load speed, but i don't want it.

the error i got: "Dynamic server usage: Page couldn't be rendered statically because it used 'headers'."

version-controller.tsx -->

```
import { headers } from "next/headers";

export const versionControl = () => {
    const headersList = headers();
    const userAgent = headersList.get("user-agent");
    const isMobile = /iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android|webOS|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(userAgent as string)
    return isMobile
}
```

[postId]/page.tsx -->

```
export async function generateStaticParams() {
  const post = await db.post.findMany()
  return post.map(post => ({postId: post.id}))
}

const PostId = async () => {
      const isMobile = versionControl()
      return (
        <div>
          {isMobile
          ? <MobileVersion />
          : <DesktopVersion />
          }
        </div>
    );
  }

export default PostId;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs:

`headers()` is a Dynamic Function whose returned values cannot be known ahead of time. Using it in a layout or page will opt a route into dynamic rendering at request time.

It seems like these won't work together. You would have to dynamically fetch the data in `PostId` as well.